# Custom Numeric Spinner Bootstrap jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, spinner, numeric

I am in need of a numeric input with updown arrows on the right to select a number. However, the step changes depending on the value, and values are rounded to different places (you can see the fiddle for the example).

Now I have tried 3 different approaches to this:

**Bootstrap - type="number"** = Preferred method

I have attempted rounding and step changes but unsuccessfully. It works if I only use the updown buttons, however if I enter 2000000 as an example it shows it is invalid. Furthermore, this won't work in Firefox. When researching this issue I came accross *Modernizr* but was unsure how to implement it (will look into this more once the primary issue is resolved)

**jQuery UI Spinner**

Couldn't really get the rounding and steps working as with the Bootstrap attempt. Also, styles conflict so would require CSS modifications.

**Custom Attempt**

I've attempted my own approach as shown in the fiddle. I still have to add functions for the button clicks. Couldn't get the thing to fill the container div when using span12 for some reason.

```
My (failed) results so far: http://jsfiddle.net/rZyZW/
```

I probably have overlooked a simple method or am going in the wrong direction with this, hopefully someone can help!

> **EDIT***
>
> Check out @rbaker86's response below, great solution to my issue with rounding and changing the step.
>
> Just need to get this to work with Firefox!

Comment: I realise the HTML5 tag is not recognised in Firefox, is there any way to ammend the existing code without having to resort to a 3rd party script?

Comment: @Stano thank you for your help, I think I'll go with the jQuery UI spinner and try to sort out the CSS issues - may have to open a new question :/

Answer (score 2):

Your code was okay. It just needed the scope sorting out. Also notice that i've only used a single jQuery selector.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rZyZW/1/

```
$("#test").change(function(){
    $self = $(this);
    var val = $self.val();

    if(val < 200){
        $self.prop('step','50');
        $self.val('200');
    }else if(val < 1000){
        $self.prop('step','50');
        $self.val(Math.round(val/50)*50);
    }else if(val > 1000 & val < 10000){
        $self.prop('step','100');
        $self.val(Math.round(val/100)*100);
    }else if(val > 10000 & val < 50000){
        $self.prop('step','250');
        $self.val(Math.round(val/250)*250);
    }else if(val > 50000 & val < 100000){
        $self.prop('step','500');
        $self.val(Math.round(val/500)*500);
    }else if(val > 100000){
        $self.prop('step','1000');
        $self.val(Math.round(val/1000)*1000);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! My only issue now is trying to get it to work with Firefox, do you have any ideas?

edit* can't upvote unfortunately, not enough rep :(

Comment: This code works only in Chrome. Do you know how to create a working jQueryUI spinner with that customized code?